# Why big image cat no stay top all thumbnail dog image When test on ie 7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Why big image cat no stay top all thumbnail dog image When test on ie 7 ?

i test on other , big image cat will stay top of all thumbnail dog image,

But when i test on ie , big image cat not stay top of all thumbnail dog image,

How can i do for move big image cat stay top of all thumbnail dog image on ie ?

http://jsfiddle.net/e2hosyoj/

```
<div style=" float: left; position: relative;">
    <span style="position: absolute; left: 0px; z-index: 999;">
        <div tyle="left: 99px; opacity: 1;">
            <img src="http://www.catchannel.com/images/kitten-older-cat.jpg">
        </div>
    </span>
    <span style="list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
        <div style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
            <img border="0" src="http://www.catchannel.com/images/kitten-older-cat.jpg" width="80" height="80">                  
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div style=" float: left; position: relative;">   
    <span style="list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
        <div style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
            <img border="0" src="http://assets.dogtime.com/asset/image/513f90ddb424393c9900067c/TN-dog-news.jpg" width="80" height="80">                 
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div style=" float: left; position: relative;">   
    <span style="list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
        <div style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
            <img border="0" src="http://www.youpet.com/graphics/animals/american-eskimo-dog-dog.jpg" width="80" height="80">                  
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div style=" float: left; position: relative;">    
    <span class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail3" style="list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
        <div class="imgWrap" style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
            <img border="0" src="http://bestclipartblog.com/clipart-pics/dog-clipart-3.gif" width="80" height="80">                 
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. Are you just trying to have the big cat image on top with thumbnails below it? Right now, all that's happening is your cat image is completely overlapping everything (in all browsers).

Comment: @nomwery geqoilu, can you elaborate more? what you exactly want to do? Because your fiddle looks same in all browsers.

Comment: it's not work on ie7